# Counting li elements with data-filter-class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to count li elements with data-filter-class "men". Below is the code snippet.

```
<ul id="cards">
    <li data-filter-class="men"></li>
    <li data-filter-class="women"></li>
    <li data-filter-class="men"></li>
    <li data-filter-class="kids"></li>
    <li data-filter-class="women"></li>
    <li data-filter-class="men"></li>
</ul>
```

```js
var filterType ='men'; //filter type received at runtime.
var category_count = $('#cards li[data-filter-class="+filterType+"]').length;
console.log(filterType + " count " + category_count);
```

Results : 0
Expected: 3

Actually

```
var category_count = $('#cards > li').length;
```

Results : 6

Can someone please point out where I am getting wrong in the first query?
I am new to learning jQuery so please excuse me.

Comment: Use quotes properly  `$('#cards li[data-filter-class="' + filterType + '"]').length;`

Comment: Thanks got this working now with fixing quots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `category_count` does not have proper string interpolation, you will want to filter like so:

```
var category_count = $('#cards li[data-filter-class="'+filterType+'"]').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close string while using `filterType`, see correct code

```
$('#cards li[data-filter-class="'+filterType+'"]').length;
```